# Sokoban in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I don't know if this is a proper question, but if I want to write a Sokoban game in Haskell (or other functional programming languages), what's the differences with writing it in C? [Edit: does Haskell have any advantages over C in Sokoban ?]

I would like to ask this question because of two reasons. First, my only interest in programming is to write Sokoban programs (I have already written several sokoban programs). Second, I've read some introduction/tutorial articles about Haskell, but have no idea how these new methods can be applied to the Sokoban logic.

Comment: your only interest is writing Sokoban-clones? Really?? .. well to be honest: don't bother with Haskell - you will only learn useless (for you) stuff ... spend your time learning graphic-libs like OpenGL, DirectX, whatever is nativ on your target platform - this way you will learn something you really need in order to improve on your "skills" ....

Comment: yes, sokoban clones, and sokoban solvers, solution optimizers as well, but not too much concern about graphical appearances

Comment: but the comment stands - Haskell is a pure FP language and is very interesting for it's own rights - but learn this new paradigm if you only want to write another sokoban-programm .. well maybe for a parallel solver but if you ask for the "differences to C"? Only answer that fits into the comment section (or the answer section) is: there is plenty of differences in syntax, thinking, problem-solving, ... - look at "Learn yourself Haskell for great good" or any other introduction to Haskell....

Comment: In that case, I'd say Haskell is a good fit, and it will be different enough to make it a very interesting task, so just go for it!

Comment: Thanks, I find your comments helpful.

Comment: I will play Haskell Sokoban all day, every day

Comment: @CarstenKönig: who does it need graphics libs? Wouldn't it be a natural fit for the command-line?

Comment: GUI? Command line? I'd say this would be a better fit for a fleet of robots.